# Fastboot: failed flashing (remote: size too large)

Tags: fastboot

I'm flashing a GSI image using fastboot. After entering `fastboot flash system system.img` I get this:

```
E:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools>fastboot flash system system.img
target reported max download size of 535822336 bytes
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
sending sparse 'system' 1/7 (523260 KB)...
OKAY [ 17.280s]
writing 'system' 1/7...
FAILED (remote: size too large)
finished. total time: 17.306s
```

I also tried to flash it using TWRP, same problem.

What's the problem? Can I make system partition larger? Please help.

Edit: I have the latest `adb` version.

Comment: I installed the latest fastboot from android.com, and i'm getting the same problem.

Comment: You cannot make the system partition larger, nor should you have to... It sounds like you are not flashing the correct system image to the device. Can you add details about the device and software image you are trying to install?

Answer (score 1):

Fastboot has an option -S Used to cut large files into small ones. Specific information can be found at man page:

```
fastboot --help
```

So, we can set the size of the crop block to 256MB:

```
fastboot flash -S 256M system system.img
```

[Source](https://www.programmersought.com/article/5694918412/)

Comment: *FAILED (remote: 'size too large')* Same error if I enter `fastboot flash -S 256M recovery recovery.img`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with boot.img
[image]

After rebooting to system and again activating Fastboot mode (Volume down+Power) it worked perfectly.
[image]

Same mobile phone, same computer, just some reboots and some minutes later.